# Ratio of Speeds of Trains

Tags: ratio

Recently, I came across a question:

> A train $T_1$ from station $P$ to $Q$, and, the other train $T_2$ from station $Q$ to $P$, start simultaneously. After they meet, the trains reach their destinations after $9$ hours and $16$ hours respectively. The ratio of their speeds is ___.
>   (*i*)  $2:3$
>   (*ii*) $4:3$
>   (*iii*) $6:7$
>   (*iv*) $9:16$

The only formula I remembered was
$$
  \text{Speed} = \frac{\text{Distance}}{\text{Time}} \cdotp
$$
I couldn't solve the question. It became more and more complex when I tried using this formula directly. Later I found out that the correct answer is (*ii*) $4:3$. The only explanation given was $\sqrt{16}:\sqrt{9}$. I can't understand how
$$
  \sqrt{\operatorname{Time}(T_2)} : \sqrt{\operatorname{Time}(T_1)}
$$
is the right formula to solve such kind of questions?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892007/word-problem-time-and-distance-driving-problem/2892023#2892023).

Comment: Trying to memorize formulas in order to solve math problems will not get you far. The times the trains needed to reach their destinations were $t+9$ and $t+16$ respectively, $t$ is the time when they met. You know that the distance they traveled was the same, can you figure out the result?

Comment: To expand on what @tst is saying, if you tried to remember formulas for every question like this, there would be a _lot_ of formulas, and trying to decide which one is appropriate in each case would be a nightmare. It's much better to know a few, really important formulas (like $\text{speed} = \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$) and then derive the formula you need for any other problem using those, use the new formula you just derived, then forget about it.

Comment: @tst I totally agree. That's why I asked the question here to understand how the formula actually works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to introduce a third point, where they meet: $M$. Then we know the following things:

1. The time $T_1$ spent on $PM$ is equal to the time $T_2$ spent on $QM$
2. The time $T_1$ spent on $QM$ is equal to $9$ hours
3. The time $T_2$ spent on $PM$ is equal to $16$ hours

Also note that $\text{speed} = \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$ becomes $\text{time} = \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}$ with some elementary manipulation. Use this to make equations out of the three above facts, using sensible variables, and note that what we're after is not $\text{speed}_1$ or $\text{speed}_2$, but $\frac{\text{speed}_1}{\text{speed}_2}$.

---

Alternatively, you can game the question, and note that train 1 is clearly faster, and only one option allows that.